# mysql update field's character

Tags: mysql, database

I have following record in MySQL database:

```
id         name                         alias
1          vijay hazare                 vijay_hazare
2          ravi shastri                 ravi_shastri
3          rahul dravid                 rahul_dravid
```

I want them like this.

```
id         name                         alias
1          vijay hazare                 vijay.hazare
2          ravi shastri                 ravi.shastri
3          rahul dravid                 rahul.dravid
```

I have 6000 records in my database and I want to change _ to .(dot) in "alias" field to all table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`REPLACE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function with `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE yourtable SET `alias`=REPLACE(`alias`,'_','.');
```